# Unexpected quantile using quantile scale. Bug?

Tags: d3.js

I am working with the following set of numbers, which are my domain:

```
[-17,-17,-13,-12,-10,-9,-8,-7,-7,-6,-6,-5,-5,-4,-3,-2,-2,-2,-2,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,11,11,11,12,14,15,18,19,19,22,36,39,50]
```

My range is a set of 6 colors, as follows:

```
["rgb(255,232,0)", "rgb(20,162,212)", "rgb(175,94,156)", "rgb(0,177,106)", "rgb(247,148,30)", "rgb(0,82,156)"]
```

My color scale is set as follows:

```
var scaleToAssignColor = d3.scale.quantile()
.domain([-17,-17,-13,-12,-10,-9,-8,-7,-7,-6,-6,-5,-5,-4,-3,-2,-2,-2,-2,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,11,11,11,12,14,15,18,19,19,22,36,39,50])
.range(["rgb(255,232,0)", "rgb(20,162,212)", "rgb(175,94,156)", "rgb(0,177,106)", "rgb(247,148,30)", "rgb(0,82,156)"]);
```

When I call scaleToAssignColor.quantiles I get the following:

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 6.333333333333343]
```

which with this domain results not in a set of six colors, but only five.

I understand that because my output range contains 6 discrete values, the returned threshold array will contain only 5 (6 - 1) values, which it does. I'm not attributing the return of only five colors to the returned threshold array (of 5) but to the following:

Quantile 1 includes any number less than, but not including, 0; 
Quantile 2 any number greater than, and including, 0 and less than, but not including, 1; 
Quantile 3 any number greater than, and including, 1 and less than, but not including, 2; 
Quantile 4 any number greater than, and including, 2 and less than, but not including, 2;
Quantile 5 any number greater than, and including, 2 and less than, but not including, 6.333; and
Quantile 6 any number greater than, and including, 6.333333333333343.

The rub is Quantile 4: as there can never be any number that is greater than, and including, 2 but also less than AND NOT including, 2, the color corresponding to Quantile 4 is never returned.

All of which begs the question: as this particular domain of numbers (a list of upvotes less downvotes for a group of comments) results in the weird Quantile 4 (as above), is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something (or using the wrong kind of scale for this particular domain and range)? I suspect it's the later.

Thanks in advance.

Harold Harper

Comment: Have you explored possibly using d3.scale.threshold instead? This would allow you to explicitly define 5 threshold values that would ensure a valid set of values falls into each of your 6 colors.  It depends what you're trying to accomplish, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the reason for this basically comes down to how quantile scales are defined:

The length (or cardinality) of the range is used to split the domain into even segments (in your example, this means that the domain is split into 6 even segments; the length of the domain is 155, so each split will occur at 155/6, or about 26 items)

The domain has 32 instances of '2', and the location of these in the ascending data mean that both the third and fourth 'splits' end up on a value of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Taking it out of comments, for posterity:

Use [threshold scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-threshold-scales). Here is a quick example:

```
coffee> d3 = require 'd3'
coffee> color = d3.scale.threshold().domain([5,30,100]).range(["red","orange","green"]);
coffee> color 6
'orange'
coffee> color 3
'red'
coffee> color 33
'green'
```